# Getting attacked when I don't have a bounty?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'm in the Dark Brotherhood on the quest recipe for disaster, but when I go to get the guy from the town the guards try to kill me even though I don't have a bounty. I checked if the same happened in other places and they still attack me and I don't have a bounty. How can I fix this?

Comment: Did you ever commit a crime and tell the guards you'd rather die than go to prison?

Comment: You might try hiding in a corner in a different hold for a week (so that the town and its guards get reset). I don't know if that'll fix it, but it sounds suspiciously like a bug I encountered with Faralda in Winterhold the other day.

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use the command "paycrimegold" - simply use your curser and tap on a guard, then write this command.
If this doesn't work, please say what is attacking you - normal guards, bandits, the emperor men(The Occuloti) because if they attack you you can kill them and the guards might even help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to some far away place and rest for 30 days?  This resets the quest area and NPCs and might fix the problem.

Alternately refer to this [extensive answer regarding fixing quests](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241963/i-have-encountered-some-glitch-involving-an-npc-or-quest-how-do-i-fix-it/241964#241964).

Comment: When you say 30 days, do you mean in-game or real-life?

Comment: In game time of 30 days.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, but I/we need more info. Is it when you enter Markath to speak with Anton Virane? Having this info, will help us help you.

If that's the case, there's a well known bug, that the guards at Understone Keep will be hostile due to an earlier bounty. Unfortunately it's not fixed by the (Un)official patch yet. Have you tried reloading a save from before you get the quest, and then enter the area before taking the quest? My guess would be to reload an older save.

In general, and especially with mods installed, it's time saving in the long run, to make a hard save every 30 minutes or so. As in Esc > Save > New Save. It takes less than 30 seconds, but can save hours if you run into a bug like this. After a while, when you're sure you don't need the saves, it's simple to delete them to save harddrive space.

Answer (score 0):

These guards are bugged and glitched, as if they think you're a criminal, but you're not. here are some ways pf fixing this glitch.

- Wait and rest in another town or in the wilderness for 30 days or more to reset guards.
- Use the cheat on each guard, `stopcombat` to make them stop combat.
- Your bounty might be bugged, so try using `payfine` cheat.
- Cast a Calm spell on the guards which will make them unhostile, but only for a limited time!

If you're still in trouble, then you're doomed.