# Quest bug while returning Arvak's skull

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I've found the skull but I can't find the soul who Arvak belongs to. The quest marker on the map just leads me to the remains of a bone man or soul embers as they're called in the game. What do I do?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nuULwbJaYVs maybe this will help. Another thing that could have happened is that the npc was attacked and died, but that would be odd since most quest npc's are marked as essential until a quest has been completed. Quest markers can be off by a lot sometimes and lead you to the wrong location

Answer (score 2):

I've made a very thorough fix for any generic quest related bugs.

[How to fix glitches in Skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241963/i-have-encountered-some-glitch-involving-an-npc-or-quest-how-do-i-fix-it)

**Method 1 (non-console commands):**

- Leave the Soul Carin
- Sleep for 30 days
- Go back and see if the NPC has reset

**Method 2 (console commands):**

- Read up on how to use [Skyrim Console Commands](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console)
- Use combination of `sqt` + `movetoqt <quest ID>` console commands