# How to erase all crime fines in all provinces in Skyrim

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I have tried the console: player.setcrimegold 0 with all of the ids, still the fine in windhelm is stuck on 9040! I can only make it higher. I tried it with -9040 and it didn't work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may have typed in the wrong faction ID, and also have included insufficient parameters to the command.

**Pay your bounty** - `player.paycrimegold <0-1> <0-1> <faction ID>` - The first 0-1 choice refers to being sent to jail: entering 1 will let you be teleported to the respective faction's jail, entering 0 won't. The second 0-1 choice refers to keeping your stolen items: entering 0 means you do not lose your stolen items, entering 1 means you do. If you don't add any choice you will be sent to jail without losing your stolen items.

- 00028170 Crime Faction Falkreath
- 000267E3 Crime Faction Eastmarch (Windhelm)
- 00029DB0 Crime Faction Haafingar (Solitude)
- 0002816D Crime Faction Hjaalmarch (Morthal)
- 0002816e Crime Faction The Pale (Dawnstar)
- 0002816C Crime Faction The Reach (Markarth)
- 0002816B Crime Faction The Rift (Riften)
- 000267EA Crime Faction Whiterun
- 0002816F Crime Faction Winterhold
- xx018279 Crime Faction Raven Rock (Solstheim)

Answer comes from my [super answer of all Skyrim problems](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/241963/i-have-encountered-some-glitch-involving-an-npc-or-quest-how-do-i-fix-it).

Answer (score 3):

Select a guard of the faction where you have the bounty in the console and enter the following command:

```
player.paycrimegold 9040
```

This will not delete the fine, but pay it, which is basically the same.

You can also enter the factionID behind the amount, which spares you from selecting a guard.