# Skyrim: Everyone is attacking me

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dragonborn

So Im in a barrow in Solstheim. I exit, read A black book, and head to Raven Rock. touched the Earth stone for the buff. After this I walked into Raven Rock, a guard yells and i get a 40 bounty then everyone is attacking me. I tried sheathing only to get another bounty and the guard saying the response to the "I'd rather die" option. This will keep repeating itself until I die.

I went to Whiterun with the same results: recurring bounty, overall aggression. Also for the record I am NOT a vampire.

Is there a solution/ reason for any of this?

Comment: [This answer](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/241964/79975) is a good first couple steps in solving almost all NPC oddities.

Comment: Are you using any mods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some generic, "works for all system" fixes pulled from a more thorough answer [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/241964/79975).

If you play on the PC, please refer to the referenced answer with multiple console command based solutions (paying off crime, changing faction, respawning/resetting NPC, etc.)

---

## In-game Fix

- Go to a far away location (why?  you want the area to be unloaded from active use so it can [reset](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Respawning#Schedule))
- Sleep for 30 days straight (this is the longest time needed for reset)

This should fix a lot of general NPC glitches like missing NPCs, NPCs attacking you on sight, not talking/responding, not following you, etc.

Comment: Ill try this and get back to you. Will any dungeon work fine? or do i have to be in the mainland far from NPCs?

Comment: I waited 31 days in kolbjorn barrow and it seemed to have resolved this issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If you play on PC, consider using the player.paycrimegold Command on the console. Just go into your console and target the guard and type player.paycrimegold   (X = 1 Remove stolen items. 0 Don't remove stolen items. Y = 1 Go to jail. 0 Don't go to jail.)

(Sometimes, does not pay off your bounty fully.)