# Skyrim Skjor wandered far from home

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I had started the "The Silver Hand"  quest but Skjor was no where to be seen. I had to glitch out of the map to find him and talk to him. He now isn't going to the underfordge to make me a werewolf. Help please

Comment: You should post the platform, on PC this can probably be fixed with console commands, but on console you'll have to get more creative (or reload a save).

Comment: You found him and talked to him? Where is he?

Answer (score 3):

You can perform a cell reset for the area where Skjor is.

Go to far away place, sleep for 30 days straight.

For more solutions and in-depth explanation, please refer to [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/241964/79975).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to load an earlier save file, or restart the game from the last time you saved. Sorry i couldn't be more of a help, but it could just be a minor glitch that will disappear next time you are on. :(