# Skyrim: Remastered for Xbox one - wuthrad is gone

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I completed the quest to get the horn of wurgen windcaller and did the first of the blades quest with Delphine and then proceeded to go to high hrothgar to give argenir the horn. When I gave it to him all the greybeards assembled, except master wuthrad, and argenir told he that wuthrad would now teach me the last word in unrelenting force. I went outside and checked my map and noticed that the quest marker for wuthrad is waaaay south of hrothgar and I figure that he somehow ended up there.  I tried reloading old save but they all have the same issue and I'm not crazy far in the game but I really don't wanna restart. I've heard that if you can manage to get close enough to hit him with an arrow you can aggro him all the way back but I'm just wondering if someone managed to find a simpler fix.
Thanks!

Comment: Would you perchance mean master Wulfgar? Wuuthrad is the weapon given you you at the end of the Companion quest line.

Comment: Also, are you sure that you have the correct quests selected for tracking? Sometimes the game (at least the PC version) is inconsistent on how it auto-selects the tracked quests when their status changes.

Comment: Just as a note, this is [a known issue for the Xbox One version of Skyrim SE](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:The_Horn_of_Jurgen_Windcaller#Bugs).

Comment: One of the suggested fixes I've seen is to find him in the mountains (wherever he wandered off to), try to maneuver him such that he's near the edge of a cliff with a road below, then use Unrelenting Force to push him off. It shouldn't aggro him, and he may start walking along the road back to High Hrothgar. Worth a shot.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform a cell reset for the area where Wulfgar is.

Go to far away place, sleep for 30 days straight.

For more solutions and in-depth explanation, please refer to [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/241964/79975).

Answer (score 1):

There is a new 1.1 patch for missing NPCs.

From the patch notes:

- Fixed rare issue with NPCs not appearing in proper locations

http://www.gamespot.com/articles/skyrim-special-edition-patch-notes-revealed/1100-6445223/

Answer (score 0):

You can try searching Hrothgar and see if you can find him on your own. If not is he on the map? If so just take a hike and visit the old man meditating in the middle of nowhere.